# Как закруглить края заднего фона в python colorama?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код:`print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLUE + "Hello")`
как закруглить края фона?
Если нельзя, то с помощью каких библиотек это можно сделать?

Comment: Чтобы в терминале/консоли цветной прямоугольник позади текста был с закругленными краями? Вряд ли это возможно. Проще свой аналог терминала сделать через GUI-библиотеку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это скорее всего невозможно)))